# Conditional Jump при передаче массива из функции

Tags: c, утечка-памяти, valgrind

````
``` 
void *to_upper(const char *str){
    size_t n = 1;
    char *result = NULL;
    result = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
    if (result != NULL){
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s21_strlen(str); i++){
            if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122){
                result[i] = str[i]-32;
            }
            else{
                result[i] = str[i];
            }
            n++;
            result = realloc(result, n);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```
````

Написал функцию выше. По функционалу все работает, но когда прогоняю через valgrind выдает "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)". Не понимаю совершенно как она может остаться неинициализированной(.

Применяю функцию в следующем коде:

```
int main(){

    // upper test
    printf("to_upper test\n");
    char str1[] = "HelLowWorld12345!?/abcd";
    char test_good[] = "HELLOWWORLD12345!?/ABCD";
    char *temp = NULL;
    temp = s21_to_upper(str1);
    if (temp != NULL){
        printf("expected result: %s\n", test_good);
        printf("function result:%s\n", temp);
        if (strcmp(test_good, temp) == 0){
            printf("TEST SUCSESS!\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("TEST FAIL!\n");
        }
        free(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не к теме вопроса, но в `result = realloc(result, n);` ведь `realloc` теоретически может и `NULL` вернуть...

Comment: Его тоже нужно проверить на NULL?

Comment: Нужно присваивать в отдельную переменную и проверять её. При ошибке выделения памяти realloc возвращает NULL и старый указатель остаётся валидным. При таком присваивании старый указатель будет потерян, т.е. произойдёт утечка.

Comment: Нужно. И — но уже по причине эффективности — добавлять по одному байту тоже решение не лучшее, *крайне* неэффективное... Тем более вы же *заранее* знаете размер строки! И кстати, а нулевой символ в результат вы не добавляете?...

Comment: Текст ошибки приводите полностью. А вообще в строке никогда не инициализируется последний байт, который для С-строки должен быть нулевым. Вычисление дины строки на каждой итерации с последующей реаллокацией на один байт больше - пустая трата ресурсов.